# How can I get sendgrid entries from send email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sendgrid

I use one sendgrid account in multiple projects, and use a same send email per project. Now I want to fetch the "Bounces" and "Invalid Emails" entries for specify project, can I get them with the same send mail?

Answer (score 2):

SendGrid does not store the from address for consumption with these API's so what you are looking to do unfortunately isn't possible this way.

Two options I recommend looking into as an alternative are:

1) Use [subusers](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181918-What-are-Subusers-). This will allow you to have separate accounts under the same parent account. You'd have to change your credentials and query for the bounces and invalid emails separately.

2) Use [categories](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/categories.html) and the [event webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html). SendGrid will send you a post request containing the event type and the category you added to the email.

Comment: I think subusers is what I need, but seems I need to handle the current data, thanks @eddiezane

Answer (score 1):

there is also unique arugments option to send with emails. use this option as a name or id of the project. then later fetch status of these emails via this unique arguments.

I recently done this work, let me know if you need any help.